# KeyError: 'access_token' during OAuth 2.0 authentication using Spotify API

Tags: python-3.x, flask, oauth-2.0, spotify, restful-authentication

I'm building a simple application to learn Python 3 and Flask. The goal is to consume data from the Spotify API and for that I need to authenticate using OAuth 2.0.

I'm able to provide my credentials to Spotify Accounts however during the callback the following error is happening:

```
File "app.py", line 59, in callback
    access_token = response_data["access_token"]
KeyError: 'access_token'
```

Code sample:

```
post_request = requests.post(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, data=code_payload, headers=headers)

response_data = json.loads(post_request.text)
access_token = response_data["access_token"]
token_type = response_data["token_type"]
expires_in = response_data["expires_in"]
refresh_token = response_data["refresh_token"]
```

This is the request response sample from the [API documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/):

```
{
   "access_token": "NgCXRK...MzYjw",
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "scope": "user-read-private user-read-email",
   "expires_in": 3600,
   "refresh_token": "NgAagA...Um_SHo"
}
```

I'm quite lost. Not sure if it's something related to the API response content or how the application is parsing it with json.loads(post_request.text).

**EDIT**: After getting the HTTP status code I'm able to have an idea of the problem:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

However I still can't figure it out what is wrong with my request:

```
authentication_token = request.args['code']
code_payload = {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": str(authentication_token),
    "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI
}
encoded_oauth2_tokens = base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).encode())
headers = {"Authorization": "Basic {}".format(encoded_oauth2_tokens)}
post_request = requests.post(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, data=code_payload, headers=headers)
post_request.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: From `b64encode` documentation:
**Encode the bytes-like object s using Base64 and return the encoded bytes.**

Try calling `encoded_oauth2_tokens.decode()` when you create headers.

Also, you should include scope into `code_payload`.

Comment: Scope is not needed, my mistake

Comment: @HarrySky you got it! .decode() did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you actually getting data from Spotify Web API and not error response?

This is what I use and it works well

```
@dataclass
class Tokens:
    access: str
    refresh: str
    expires_at: int

# Class that sets up authorization_headers
# Class method
def get_tokens(self, code_from_redirect_uri: str) -> bool:
        payload: dict = {'redirect_uri': self._redirect_uri, 'code': code_from_redirect_uri,
                        'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'scope': self._scope}
        response: Response = post(OAUTH_TOKEN_URL, data=payload, headers=self.authorization_headers)
        # When we don't get the OK response - we assume code was bad
        if response.status_code != 200:
            return False

        token_info: dict = response.json()
        self.tokens = Tokens(token_info['access_token'], token_info['refresh_token'], token_info['expires_in']*1000 + time())
        return True
```

Comment: I'll try this when I get home. Checking the response status is a must that I forgot to do, thanks.

Comment: Let me know if this answer helped you

Comment: I'll edit the question with further information after getting the HTTP status code.