# requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, oauth-2.0, spotify

I'm quite new to Python 3 and Flask, and I'm currently building a simple web application to consume data from the Spotify API.

The OAuth 2.0 authentication flow is almost working since I'm able to call https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize:

During the POST request to the API I'm getting HTTP 400:

```
authentication_token = request.args['code']
code_payload = {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": str(authentication_token),
    "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI
}
encoded_oauth2_tokens = base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).encode())
headers = {"Authorization": "Basic {}".format(encoded_oauth2_tokens)}
post_request = requests.post(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, data=code_payload, headers=headers)
post_request.raise_for_status()
```

EDIT: Response body:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - b'{"error":"invalid_client"}'
```

Not sure what is wrong in the request.

Comment: What is the body of the response?

Comment: @Kaszaq printed the response body using: print(str(post_request.content), file=sys.stderr). I was not able to get much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to correct the issue with a hint from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734293/keyerror-access-token-during-oauth-2-0-authentication-using-spotify-api).

Adding encoded_oauth2_tokens.decode() to the header was the missing piece to make a valid request to the Spotify API. The code stands as it follows:

```
encoded_oauth2_tokens = base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).encode())
headers = {"Authorization": "Basic {}".format(encoded_oauth2_tokens.decode())}
```