# Python YouTube data api v3 KeyError: "access_token'

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, keyerror

I was writing a program to manage Youtube Accounts collectively with Python, but I get this error even though I added youtube data api key, client id, client secret to the file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 51, in main
    access_token = login_google(email, password)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 35, in login_google
    return json.loads(response.text)["access_token"]
KeyError: 'access_token'
```

When I select the account file, it gives me the above error when it should automatically ask me for the YouTube channel id to subscribe. What should I do? Can you help me?

```py
import os
import json
import requests
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

# Google API anahtarınızı ve diğer gerekli anahtarları buraya girin
API_KEY = "hided"
CLIENT_ID = "hided"
CLIENT_SECRET = "hided"
REDIRECT_URI = "hided"

# Kullanıcının seçtiği dosyayı okuma
def read_file():
    Tk().withdraw()
    filename = askopenfilename()
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        accounts = file.readlines()
    return accounts

# Google API ile giriş yapma
def login_google(email, password):
    data = {
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
        "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI,
        "grant_type": "password"
    }
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    response = requests.post("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", data=data, headers=headers)
    return json.loads(response.text)["access_token"]

# YouTube kanalına abone olma
def subscribe_youtube(channel_id, access_token):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
        "Content-Length": "0"
    }
    response = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key=" + API_KEY, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)

# Programın çalışması
def main():
    accounts = read_file()
    for account in accounts:
        email, password = account.split(":")
        access_token = login_google(email, password)
        channel_id = input("Enter the channel ID: ")
        subscribe_youtube(channel_id, access_token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide the Python code you are using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am providing the python code, can you have a look again?

Comment: does response.text give you some clues? Maybe its the same issue like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734293/keyerror-access-token-during-oauth-2-0-authentication-using-spotify-api) look at the comments and the decoding.